# Redirect To www from non www site for subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from http://domain.com/folder/ to http://www.domain.com/folder/

I have tried below code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

AND

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/folder/index.html [R=301,NC]
```

It redirects to http://domain.com/ to http://www.domain.com/
Not http://domain.com/folder/ to http://www.domain.com/folder/

also it redirect to http://domain.com/folder/ to http://www.domain.com/
But not to http://www.domain.com/folder/

Please suggest what issue and help to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: @crypticツ: I need redirection to non www to www within subfolder. Above code work for only main domain not for sub folders. :P

Comment: @crypticツ: You don't understand difference between Apache and .htaccess code? I don't have rights to edit Apache but I can edit .htaccess.

Comment: Did you bother to look at the other answers on that page? My guess is you didn't. Because you make no effort in looking up the solution to something that has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It should only redirect `http://domain.com/folder/` to `http://www.domain.com/folder/`